# Esper - redundant output using named window

Tags: esper

I'm new to Esper and started testing using EPL Online.
When I create a named windows and insert event into it, I get duplicate output from both statements.
For example:

create window OrdersNamedWindow.win:keepall() as OrderMapEventType;

insert into OrdersNamedWindow select * from OrderMapEventType;

Is there a way to deduplicate the output from both statements?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EPL Online (http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com) in the "All Output Events" displays every possible output . In this case the output of the statement inserting into the named window as well as all the inserts and removes for the named window. You can assign a name to each statement and get output per statement.

```
@name('named window') create window OrdersNamedWindow.win:keepall() as OrderMapEventType;
```

Now in the tab "Output Per Statement" is shows you sub-tabs with the output of each statement separated.

Comment: Thanks. I know you can assign a name and see the output on the tabs. The thing is when I use the actual Esper software I also get duplicate output with the mentioned statements. Is it possible to "hide" the output from the inserts from the named window? So that I only see the output from the insert into statement?

Comment: If you don't attach a listener you don't get output.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar case by adding std:firstunique(expressions) into create window-clause